# Unity freezes after setting UI gameobjects to true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am making a game, and whenever you press tab an inventory should pop up. Right now its just some gray boxes and TMP. I have an empty GO, with two other empty GOs. Pockets and a backpack. On both it has the boxes and TMP as a child.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventorySys : MonoBehaviour
{
    //getting the player, and the OV_playerData
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    private OV_PlayerData playerData;
    //Backpack Bool
    private bool bag;

    //Getting the inventory
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Inventory;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject backpack;
    //Open inventory bool (useful for the backpack to be showing only when the inventory is open)
    private bool OpenInv;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerData = player.GetComponent<OV_PlayerData>();
        bag = playerData.Backpack;
        //making sure that the inventory is set to false
        Inventory.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            Inventory.SetActive(true);
            OpenInv = true;
        }
        while (OpenInv == true)
        {
            if (bag == true)
            {
                backpack.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

After I run the game it works normally until I press tab when it just freezes.

Comment: You dont show how OpenInv ever changes to false. So yes. It will freeze or even crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no exit condition for your while loop.

You don't need a while loop to make sure something is visible constantly, when a game object is active its going to be rendered until you set it inactive again.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventorySys : MonoBehaviour
{
    //getting the player, and the OV_playerData
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    private OV_PlayerData playerData;
    //Backpack Bool
    private bool bag;

    //Getting the inventory
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Inventory;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject backpack;
    //Open inventory bool (useful for the backpack to be showing  only when the inventory is open)
    private bool OpenInv;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerData = player.GetComponent<OV_PlayerData>();
        bag = playerData.Backpack;
        //making sure that the inventory is set to false
        Inventory.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            OpenInv = true;
            Inventory.SetActive(true);

            if (bag == true)
            {
                backpack.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```